Block redirection to a particular url pattern
I've a web application which leads to multiple redirection via 302 response from backend. I want to stop the execution when it is redirected to a particular url eg: xyz.com/bp/invite?* and capture the parameters. I will then fire the request with the parameters captured to on my dev-box for debugging. Note the request is not idempotent. I don't want it to hit xyz.com/bp/invite?* as replaying will lead to a different code path.
How can I do this? Which browser and tool to use for this? Tried using ublock Origin extension, it didn't block the request.
